# How to add a new page at the end of the report in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I want to add a new page at the end of my report. I have tried but the new page is coming next to the first page.

I have some sections in reports in which I want 500 text/words to be written and when it exceeds, the remaining text should go to that new page.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Section Expert. In your report footer, set it to create a new page before it is printed (In 'Section Expert', select the Report Footer -> 'Paging' tab -> Check 'New Page Before' checkbox).

Following the above directions will give you one extra page at the end of the report.